# What can be done to make handleChange method correctly formats user input into desired range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following field where I want the desired output to be in the format of `XX.xxxxxx` by adding leading and trailing zeros based on the data

```
<TextBoxField
  id="location-latitude-control"
  title="Required: Latitude"
  name="location.latitude"
  value={location.latitude}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleBlur={this.handleBlur}
/>
```

What can I do to fix my handleChange method to properly format user's input:

```
handleChange = value => {
  const numsAfterDot = 6;
  const isNegative = value < 0;
  const hasDecimals = value.includes(".");
  let absolute = Math.abs(value).toString();
  if (isNaN(absolute)) return;
  else {
    const split = absolute.split(".");
    let start = hasDecimals ? split[0] : absolute.slice(0, 2);
    let rest = hasDecimals ? split[1] : absolute.slice(2, numsAfterDot)
    start = start.padStart(2, "0");
    rest = rest.padEnd(numsAfterDot, "0");
    const result = `${start}.${rest}`;
    return isNegative ? `-${result}` : result;
  }
}
```

**Expected behavior for latitude:**

```
"7.0" should convert to "07.000000"
"12.1234561" should convert to "12.123456"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to increase the length of the numbers. Then use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get the correct parts and then concatenate them to get your result.

```js
const numsAfterDot = 6;

const tests = ["7.0", "12.1234561", "0.12", "2.5", "7", "123", "1234", "123456789", "-123"];

const answers = tests.map((test) => {
  const absolute = Math.abs(test).toString();
  const hasDecimals = absolute.includes(".");
  
  const split = absolute.split(".");
  let start = hasDecimals ? split[0] : absolute.slice(0, 2);
  let rest = hasDecimals ? split[1].slice(0, numsAfterDot) : absolute.slice(2, numsAfterDot + 2);
  
  start = start.padStart(2, "0");
  rest = rest.padEnd(numsAfterDot, "0");
  
  const result = `${start}.${rest}`;
  
  return test < 0 ? `-${result}` : result;
});

console.log(answers);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works really well. I see one issue though. When I tested the data by typing `7.0` into the field. It converted the data into `70.000000` instead of `07.000000`. Any way you can add this scenario as well to your snippet above?

Comment: I see another issue `.12` returns `0..120000` instead of `00.120000`

Comment: I see you have updated your solution. Really appreciate it. All scenarios looks good except for the following. When I enter `.12`. I see `0..120000` instead of `00.120000`.

Comment: @dev101 Yes i totally forgot about decimals, but i have changed my code to take this into account aswell. All should be good right now.

Comment: no worries. You have been a great help! Everything looks good now except this one that I just noticed. When I am entering `2.5`, it's getting converted into `25.000000` instead of `02.500000`. Is this also possible to fix?

Comment: @dev101 Good catch, all fixed now!

Comment: Yes - all good now. I am so pleased! Thank you very much @theblackgigant from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Just noticed one more scenario @theblackgigant. When I enter `12.1234561` to the field. It does not format into `12.123456`. Can you please update your snippet above with this scenario if you do happen to see this msg of mine?

Comment: I just updated my post with 2 scenarios that are failing @theblackgigant. When you please see my notifications can you please help me out again?

Comment: @dev101 Just needed to reorder some lines and added an additional `slice()` thats it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.pow` and `toFixed`.

```js
let handleChange = (val) => {
  const len = (+val).toString().length;
  if (len > 1) {
    const pow = val > -1 ? len - 2 : len - 3;

    return "" + (val / Math.pow(10, pow)).toFixed(6);
  }
  return "0" + (+val).toFixed(6);
};

console.log(handleChange("7.0")); //07.000000
console.log(handleChange("123456789")); //12.345679
console.log(handleChange("12")); //12.000000
console.log(handleChange("1")); //1.0000000
console.log(handleChange("-123")); //-12.300000
console.log(handleChange("1234")); //12.340000
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and providing your solution. It works well. I see one issue though. When I tested the data by typing `7.0` into the field. It converted the data into `0.700000` instead of `07.000000`. Also `.12` returns `0.012000` instead of `00.120000`. Any way you can cover these scenarios as well to your snippet above?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with - I'm sure others can do this way more graciously.

```
//Convert to string
let valToString = val.toString().split("");

//Trim string to max number of characters
let trimmedVal = valToString.slice(0, 8);

//Find first integer (accounting for negative numbers)
let firstInt = trimmedVal.findIndex((element) => element.match(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/));

//Add a dot after 2nd integer
trimmedVal.splice(firstInt + 2, 0, ".");

//Fill with zeroes as needed
for (let i = trimmedVal.length - firstInt; i < 9; i++) {
  trimmedVal.push("0");
}

return trimmedVal.join("");
```

Comment: Rubens, thank you for your solution. All scenarios works great except the followings:
`.12` should convert it to `00.120000`
`7.0` should convert it to `07.000000`